# Qt: Ignore MouseButtonRelease events when widget is hidden

Tags: c++, qt

The Documentation for QWidget says this:

> mouseReleaseEvent() is called when a mouse button is released. A
> widget receives mouse release events when it has received the
> corresponding mouse press event. This means that if the user presses
> the mouse inside your widget, then drags the mouse somewhere else
> before releasing the mouse button, your widget receives the release
> event. There is one exception: if a popup menu appears while the mouse
> button is held down, this popup immediately steals the mouse events.

It also says this:

> If you create new widgets in the mousePressEvent() the
> mouseReleaseEvent() may not end up where you expect, depending on the
> underlying window system (or X11 window manager), the widgets'
> location and maybe more

In my programme, the is a context where the user can change the current visible widget by pressing  Enter. If they click and hold on a toolbar button and press enter while the mouse is still pressed, they can send the mouse release event to the now hidden widget. This is a problem as the actions in the toolbar of the now hidden page, relate to a state which has been deinitialised when the active widget was changed.

The desired behaviour would be for the changing of active widget to somehow 'cancel' or 'release' the old widget's claim to the coming mouse release event even though it (or one of its children) received the corresponding mouse press event, and for the action in the toolbar not to be triggered.

Is there any way to do this? Or does anyone have any guidance on what I might be looking for?

Thanks

Comment: I think you need to override `eventFilter` (see https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qobject.html#eventFilter) and then use `installEventFilter` (see https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qobject.html#installEventFilter) for widgets you need

Answer (score 1):

One options is by creating eventFilter function (either in widget itself (if your own) or parent widget), installing it with installEventFilter and then checking for mouse release event type and only accept the event if widget's isVisible() returns true.

Another option (in case you have your own Qt based widget class) is to override mouseReleaseEvent and do the same visibility check in there.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Would that not require installing the widget as an event filter for all of the widgets and buttons it contains? The toolbar button I mentioned in the original question is not the only one and the widget which has this problem is also not unique.

Comment: You can do widget->installEventFilter(this) in the parent widget to handle only a single widget in parent's eventFilter function.

Comment: Overriding specific event handler e.g`mouseReleaseEvent` does not allow to stop event, so it can not be used

Comment: Meanwhile it would be better to install one event filter to all widgets, those operates in the same way depending from visibility, and stop specific events there, if the watched object is not visible